# Plotting line chart with date vs frequency in d3 by angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg, linechart

I am trying to make a simple chart in d3, where I am plotting date (as string) vs frequency. But, I am getting error. Can someone help me out?

**SNIPPET:**

```
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.12/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>

</head> 

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

  <svg width="1000" height="500"></svg>

<script>
//module declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//Controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

    //custom data 
    var data = [
        {x: "2016-01-10", y: "10.02"},
        {x: "2016-02-10", y: "15.05"},
        {x: "2016-03-10", y: "50.02"},
        {x: "2016-04-10", y: "40.01"},
        {x: "2016-05-10", y: "10.08"},
        {x: "2016-06-10", y: "29.07"},
        {x: "2016-07-10", y: "45.02"}
    ];

    var mySVG = d3.select("svg");
    var svgWidth = mySVG.attr("width");
    var svgHeight = mySVG.attr("height");
    var margins = {top: 20,right: 20,bottom: 20,left: 50};

    var xRange = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([margins.left, svgWidth - margins.right])
      .domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {return d.x;}), d3.max(data, function (d) {return d.x;}) ]);

    var yRange = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([svgHeight - margins.top, margins.bottom])
      .domain([d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.y; }), d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.y;}) ]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xRange)
                .tickSize(5)
                .tickSubdivide(true);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yRange)
                .tickSize(5)
                .orient("left")
                .tickSubdivide(true);


        mySVG.append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (svgHeight - margins.bottom) + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

        mySVG.append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margins.left) + ",0)")
          .call(yAxis);

        var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {
          return xRange(d.x);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
          return yRange(d.y);
        })
        .interpolate('linear');

      mySVG.append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", lineFunc(data))
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");
  });

</script> 

</body> 

</html>
```

** Error: **

[image]

```
        var xRange = d3.scale.linear() <<<<< Error line
```

Please, help me in making the line chart along with x and y axis with date and frequency on them plotted. Kindly, help out.

**Updated Snippet:**

```
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.12/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>

</head> 

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

  <svg width="1000" height="500"></svg>

<script>
//module declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//Controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

    //custom data 
    var data = [
        {x: "2016-01-10", y: "10.02"},
        {x: "2016-02-10", y: "15.05"},
        {x: "2016-03-10", y: "50.02"},
        {x: "2016-04-10", y: "40.01"},
        {x: "2016-05-10", y: "10.08"},
        {x: "2016-05-10", y: "29.07"},
        {x: "2016-05-10", y: "45.02"}
    ];

    var mySVG = d3.select("svg");
    var svgWidth = mySVG.attr("width");
    var svgHeight = mySVG.attr("height");
    var margins = {top: 20,right: 20,bottom: 20,left: 50};

    var xRange = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([margins.left, svgWidth - margins.right])
      .domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {return d.x;}), d3.max(data, function (d) {return d.x;}) ]);

    var yRange = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([svgHeight - margins.top, margins.bottom])
      .domain([d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.y; }), d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.y;}) ]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xRange)
                .scale(xRange)
                .tickSize(5);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yRange)
                .scale(yRange)
                .tickSize(5)
                .orient("left");


        mySVG.append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (svgHeight - margins.bottom) + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

        mySVG.append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margins.left) + ",0)")
          .call(yAxis);

        var lineFunc = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) {
          return xRange(d.x);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
          return yRange(d.y);
        })
        .curve(d3.curveLinear);

      mySVG.append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", lineFunc(data))
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");
  });

</script> 

</body> 

</html>
```

**New Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using d3 v4.x, not the old v3. Thus, you have to modify your code.

These are the necessary changes:

```
var xRange = d3.scaleLinear()//keep the domain and range

var yRange = d3.scaleLinear()//keep the domain and range

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xRange)
    .tickSize(5);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yRange)
    .tickSize(5);

var lineFunc = d3.line()//etc...
```

For the line generator, change `interpolate` for `curve`.

Also, get rid of `tickSubdivide`.

EDIT: you have additional problems in your fiddle: the values are strings, but they should be numbers. Besides that, if you're using dates, you'll have to parse them.

Here is your fiddle, without using the dates: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/fawe63t8/

Comment: d3.axisLeft(...).scale(...).tickSize(...).orient is not a function <<<<<< New error after fixes. Care a fiddle???

Comment: Are you asking me to write a fiddle?

Comment: Yep copy it ... so it runs. As, I am still facing above error making changes you said.

Comment: I've updated my code and the error me facing. Pl see.

Comment: Why don't *you* create a fiddle, so we can just change it? After all, it's *your* interest. The only thing I receive here is (rarely) an upvote.

Comment: OK, I'll check it. Meanwhile, why don't you simply change the reference for version 3? So easy!

Comment: My whole project is based on version 4.